# Vertically centering doesn't work in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment, css-transforms

I've got the following HTML markup:

```
<div class="custom-alert-window" id="alert-window">
    <span id="alert-window-text">Hi!</span>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
div.custom-alert-window{
    z-index: 100;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -156px;
    margin-left: 37.5%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
div.custom-alert-window > span{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

But for some reason, the `<span>` is not vertically centered. It does position itself 50% from the top, but the `transform: translateY(-50%);` function doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The element needs to be vertically centered in relation to its parent, if you want the element to be vertically centered in the entire page, make sure it is not wrapped in a container which has non-static positioning. Otherwise, the element will be vertically centered relative to its parent height.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azizn/6f8mertg/)

```css
div.custom-alert-window {
    width: 30%;
    height: 10%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    
    /* vertical centering */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    
    /* horizental centering */
    margin:0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

div.custom-alert-window span {
    /* vertical centering */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-alert-window" id="alert-window">
    <span id="alert-window-text">Hi!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the <span> needs to be vertically centered inside the <div>, which works only if the <span>'s position is absolute.

Comment: That's because `span` by default is an `inline` tag, setting it to `display:block;` will make `position:relative` work. see: http://jsfiddle.net/azizn/6f8mertg/1/

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it worked when I changed the position of the `span` to `absolute`.

```
div.custom-alert-window > span{
    position: absolute;
}
```